# Twilio Webhooks, validating the genuine twilio Request

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I am evaluating the Twilio Webhooks for our solution. It works charm. 
I would like detect and validate that it's Genuine TWILIO call and not a BOT/FAKE, that is making call to our EndPoint (the IPN listener, that URL we specify for Twilio WebHook listener).

I don't like the idea of checking UserAgent value contains "TwilioProxy". Do you recommend a better approach?

Comment: On the URL the WebHook is posted to, can you add some hashed secret key and validate the value? E.g. http://your-api/webhooks/twilio?hash=abc123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely [validate that a webhook is a genuine Twilio request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests).

With every webhook request Twilio sends an `X-Twilio-Signature` header with a signature in it. The signature is created using the following method:

> 1. Twilio assembles its request to your application, including the final URL and any POST fields (if the request is a POST).
> 2. If your request is a POST, Twilio takes all the POST fields, sorts them by alphabetically by their name, and concatenates the parameter name and value to the end of the URL (with no delimiter).
> 3. Twilio takes the resulting string (the full URL with query string and all POST parameters) and signs it using HMAC-SHA1 and your AuthToken as the key.

To verify the signature, you need to:

> 1. Take the full URL of the request URL you specify for your phone number or app, from the protocol (https...) through the end of the
>      query string (everything after the ?).
> 2. If the request is a POST, sort all of the POST parameters alphabetically (using Unix-style case-sensitive sorting order).
> 3. Iterate through the sorted list of POST parameters, and append the variable name and value (with no delimiters) to the end of the URL
>      string.
> 4. Sign the resulting string with HMAC-SHA1 using your AuthToken as the key (remember, your AuthToken's case matters!).
> 5. Base64 encode the resulting hash value.
> 6. Compare your hash to ours, submitted in the X-Twilio-Signature header. If they match, then you're good to go.

This is all described, with examples, on our [Security page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests). If you are using one of our [official helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) then there will be a method to verify this already built in.

Comment: I am using following approach:
RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator(); // Class of Twilio.TwiML
var isAuth = validator.IsValidRequest(HttpContext.Current, _client.IpmAuthToken);

if isAuth==TRUE,, it's Authenticated.

Comment: It's hard to read the code in your comment, but you've said the question is answered, so I hope this is positive! Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help.

Comment: I'm new to Twilio and I'm not quite clear on when we should be doing the signature verification. Should the steps to generate the hash be done before sending the message to Twilio and then stored - wait for webhook callback from Twillio - then compare? I have a Windows Service/console app that is sending the SMS to Twilio, then an asp.net MVC web app that receives and handles the SMS's status webhook callback. Presumably I need to store this hash before I send the message to Twilio so it's available to be compared when the webhook fires - correct? If so, the docs don't explicitly state that.

Comment: @lg1382 No, the signature is fully generated from the contents of the webhook along with your auth token. So, you only need the request details to create the signature. Read through the steps to verify above again and they describe how to build the signature, and if you're using a Twilio helper library, it should have a signature verifier method included that you can use.

Comment: @philnash - I found an old link from Devin Rader mentioning that you can place a "ValidateRequst (authtoken)" attribute on a TwilioController and it will do it for you... sadly my testing of that failed. When I used a bad auth token the controller still processed the request from Twilio. FYI: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/twilio-for-net-developers-part-5-twilio-client-mvc-and-webmatrix-helper-libraries.html I will reread the doc and see if I can figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: What language/platform are you developing with?

Comment: C# / MVC. "ValidateRequest" is described in that blog article as an attribute that can be applied to the TwilioController class or the Action method within that class. I only applied it to the Action method in my test. I placed my actual auth token between the double quotes where it shows: "AUTHTOKENXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" - does it require the "AUTHTOKEN" part to remain? In any case, is that documented anywhere besides a blog post? That post is fairly old so perhaps it's not relevant anymore - if so it would be great if it were updated or just removed.

Comment: Hmm, that is a very old blog post (2012). I would suggest you take a look through [this tutorial on securing endpoints in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-csharp-aspnet-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests) instead.